# convert string time to date type in java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have string like "21:00:00" which is the time. How can i convert this string to date type having time only using . The corresponding hibernate mapping  is date type and the mysql field is time.

Comment: Even the [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class has a date.

Comment: It's like 5 secs of searching in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `java.sql.Time` you retrieve the right value from your time field in mysql.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class teste {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date data = sdf.parse("21:00:00");

            Time time = new Time(data.getTime());

            System.out.println(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is

```
21:00:00
```